# Call method on downcasted class

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have a certain `SomeInterface` and I have a number of classes implementing this interface. All these classes have `someMethod()` that is not defined by the interface.

Say I have a variable `someVariable` of type `SomeInterface` and I want to call `someMethod()` on it. One way to do it is to downcast `SomeInterface` to `SomeClass` that implements `SomeInterface` and call the `someMethod` on it like this:

```
((SomeClass) someVariable).someMethod()
```

But I do not know which one of the classes that implement `SomeInterface` is stored in `someVariable`. What is the alternative clean way to call a method that is implemented by an underlying class but not defined by the interface I am coding against.

Comment: there are a pointers which might help you: if (obj instanceof SomeClass) {
((SomeClass) someVariable).someMethod()
} else if (obj instanceof SomeClass2) {....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dirtiest solution is to use reflection, using `instanceof` is a bit less dirty, but still not optimal. Least dirty solution would be to create another interface with `someMethod()` and make the classes implement that interface as well. Then you can just cast to that interface and call the method.

```
((SomeInterface) someVariable).someMethod();
```

This of course requires that you be able to modify the classes in question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to make any changes as this is an external project but thank you for laying out all the options. This is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to call the method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestI t = new Test();
        Class c = t.getClass();

        try {
           Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("someMethod");
            m.invoke(t);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here `TestI` is an interface which do not have `someMethod` in it. Using reflection get the method of the class and invoke method `someMethod` in t
object.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether `someVariable` is storing a `SomeClass` instance before calling `someMethod`

```
if (someVariable instanceof SomeClass) {
    ((SomeClass)someVariable).someMethod();
} else {
    // do something else
}
```